# How to automate the activation of role-based strategy plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am working to automate the installation and use of the role-based strategy plugin in Jenkins using ansible. At the moment I can easily install the plugin using the API. However, in order to use the plugin, it is necessary to activate it through the Jenkins UI by clicking '*Manage Jenkins*, then *Configure System* and selecting a role-based strategy.
I am having difficulty automating the activation process since it seems an API does not exist in Jenkins for that. This is my relevant ansible code

```
- name: Install a role based plugin if it does not exist
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins"
    method: POST
    user: admin
    password: bd7afbedc842418fb7fc27fdf8b3d2e4
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body: '<jenkins><install plugin="role-strategy@2.9.0" /></jenkins>'
    headers:
      Content-Type: "text/xml"
    follow_redirects: all  
  when: "'Role-based Authorization Strategy' not in plugins_output_list.content"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

After installing the plugin, is there a way I can activate it without using the UI? I really can't see any API for that purpose.

Comment: I have recently been through this (rather painful, considering that Jenkins is at the heart of a lot of DevOps based workflows) process. Unfortunately I don't have my code to hand, but I heavily used this repo https://github.com/Accenture/adop-jenkins/tree/master/resources/init.groovy.d for inspiration.

Comment: thanks for the link, i actually came across it earlier on but i dont understand how to incorporate that into Ansible code. I have never used groovy before

Comment: You will need to read up a bit on Groovy. Essentially you need to write a Groovy script similar to the one in the repo I linked to. You get Ansible to copy that script to $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/. Jenkins will run any script it finds in there after it has finished booting. I wrote my script to load a series of role configurations from a separate JSON file that is built from a dictionary in the Ansible inventory. Therefore changes to roles can be made just by changing the inventory, getting Ansible to update the JSON, then Jenkins restart.

Comment: thanks, i will try it out

Comment: I have been in need of doing something similar with matrix auth and found a nice repo that had some other groovy examples here: https://github.com/samrocketman/jenkins-bootstrap-shared/tree/master/scripts

Answer (score -2):

Your answer is [here](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/).

> Configure ALL Jenkins initial setup
>   Fully working Jenkins master with:

no hands on keyboard

no click on UI

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, show a code example etc